# Localstorage is working for first time. If I refresh page at second it is working fine

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I am using AngularJS local storage. I am facing an issue with local storage. At first when page is loaded the localstorage is assigning with null value. If I refresh at second time localstorage value is setting fine. I don't know what the issue.

**My code is.**

```
        var app = angular.module('EntityApp', ['ngRoute', 'slickCarousel']);
    app.controller('EntityAppCntroller', function($scope, $http, $window) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('IsNewPinSet') != 1) {
            var getLocation = function() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                } else {
                    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
                }
            };
            getLocation();

            function showPosition(position) {
                var latitude;
                var longitude;
                latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                localStorage.setItem('latitudeHome', latitude)
                localStorage.setItem('longitudeHome', longitude)
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'latLng': latlng
                }, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[0]) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                                var types = results[0].address_components[i].types;
                                for (var typeIdx = 0; typeIdx < types.length; typeIdx++) {
                                    if (types[typeIdx] == 'postal_code') {
                                        var pin_all = results[0].address_components[i].short_name;
                                        localStorage.setItem('pincodehome', pin_all)
                                        $scope.pin_all = pin_all;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log("No results found");
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
        }
        // $window.localStorage.getItem('pincodehome') is null
        // $window.localStorage.getItem('latitudeHome') is null
        // $window.localStorage.getItem('longitudeHome') is null
        //Common response in home page
        $http.get('someurl?pincode=' + localStorage.getItem('pincodehome') + '&lat=' + localStorage.getItem('latitudeHome') + '&lang=' + localStorage.getItem('longitudeHome'), {}).success(function(response) {
            $scope.Promotion = response.Promotion.Response;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your usage here use the native localStorage but not the $localStorage

Comment: I have uploaded my code. Please check it. I have decided not to use ng-strage.

Comment: In this case use localStorage.setItem() or $window.localStorage.setItem() to set an item.

Comment: From where are you getting the values for latitude and longitude. In your above code, both of them are not getting assigned any value but still you are setting it to localStorage.

Comment: I will update my code.I have google map scripts which get the lat, long and pin. I store them to localstorage.

Comment: `localStorage.IsNewPinSet = 22;` that's not how to set an item on localStorage

Comment: Sorry I missly used it. But why first time value is assigning null if I refresh page lat, long and pincode is setting fine.